# natural map to the homotopy fibre

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, fibration

In the paper [Homology fibrations and group completion theorem, McDuff-Segal](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mcdsegal.pdf,),
page 280, paragraph 4, line 2-line 3 and [Configuration spaces of positive and negative particles, McDuff](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938375900385), page 105, line 3-line 6:

*for a map $p:E\to B$ and $b\in B$, there is a natural map $p^{-1}(b)\to F(p,b)$ where $F(p,b)$ is the homotopy fibre.*

I find the definition of homotopy fibre on Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, page 407-409:

*Let $p: E\to B$ be a map. Let the space 
$$
E_p=\{(a,\gamma)\in E\times \text{Map}([0,1],B) \mid  \gamma(0)=p(a)\} 
$$
be topologized as a subspace of $E\times \text{Map}([0,1],B)$. For every $b\in B$, the homotopy fibre of $p$ at $b$ is defined to be the space
$$
F(p,b)=\{(a,\gamma)\in E\times \text{Map}([0,1],B)\mid  \gamma(0)=p(a), \gamma(1)=b\}.
$$*

**Question:**

How to define the natural map
$$
p^{-1}(b)\to F(p,b)?
$$
I want  to give the natural map 
by sending $a\in p^{-1}(b)$ to $(a,\gamma_a)\in F(p,b)$. However, the path $\gamma_a$ from $p(a)$ to $b$ is not uniquely determined since $B$ may not be simply connected.

Comment: Sounds like the natural map should be $a \mapsto (a,\gamma_b)$ where $\gamma_b$ is the constant path from $b$ to $b$.